# Clicking in an element on Puppeteer, using selectors

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I'm trying to use puppeteer to go to a webpage and then click in a element. I'm using page.waitForSelector() and page.click(). But I don't know what the selector should be because the div that I need to click is the child of many other div's.

The structure is something like this:

```
<div id="id_1">
    <div id="id_2">
        <div id="id_3">
            <div class="class_1">
                <div id="class_2">
        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the firefox console I just type document.getElementsByClassName("class_2").click(), and it works.

I tried doing: page.waitForSelector("#id_1 > id_2 > id_3 > .class_1 > .class_2")

Answer (score 3):

Your sample HTML has `<div id="class_2">` while your attempt on the console is clicking the `<div class="class_2">`.  So I suppose the actual `div` has classname with `class_2`, not the id.

If the page is dynamically rendered and you have to wait for `div` to show up in the DOM, the following should work.  Remember to put `await` in front.

```
await page.waitForSelector('.class_2');
page.click('.class_2');
```

If many elements have `class_2` classname, the code above only waits for the first element to appear with `class_2` classname on the page and clicks it.  If you want a specific element, you can use `#id_1 > #id_2 > #id_3 > .class_1 > .class_2` as a selector.  Remember to put the hash, `#`, in front of every ids.

However, since your `document.getElementsByClassName("class_2").click()` worked from the console.  Simply using `.class_2` as a selector should be ok.

Comment: Thank you. I tried both methods, but I keeping getting the error:
(node:10188) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: waiting for selector `.hvc2 pb-3 flex row wrap justify-left align-left noselect card` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded                                 
`.hvc2 pb-3 flex row wrap justify-left align-left noselect card` would be the class_2 in my sample

Comment: That's because the selector is not correct.  For example, `.hvc2 pb-3` means you are trying to select the element whose tag name is `<pb-3>` that is the descendants of the element with a classname `hvc2`.   You should google the `MDN selector` and read the page how to write a selector first.

Comment: Or you can simply try with the `.hvc2` as an argument of `page.waitForSelector()` and `page.click()`.

Comment: You need to replace the spaces by dots, instead of:
.hvc2 pb-3 flex row wrap justify-left align-left noselect card
It should be:
.hvc2.pb-3.flex.row.wrap.justify-left.align-left.noselect.card

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this:

```
page.waitForSelector("#class_2")
```

Comment: Yes, you are right pguardiario, I change it now.